# Linked list doesn't work when I tried to extract first element

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use my own list with a class called "NameCard" which has two variables, name and phone.

However, complier crushed when I use LFirst(LData pData).

It worked with simple int type list.

any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Here is my code.

Class name: ArrayList.cpp

```
int ArrayList::LFirst(LData* pData)
{
    if (numOfData == 0)
        return 0;

    curPosition = 0;
    *pData = arr[0];
    return 1;
}
```

Class name: NameCard.cpp

```
NameCard::NameCard()
{
}

NameCard::NameCard(const char* iName, const char* iPhone)
{
    strcpy_s(name, iName);
    strcpy_s(phone, iPhone);
}

void NameCard::ShowNameCardInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << ", phone: " << phone << std::endl;
}

int NameCard::NameCompare(char* iName)
{
    return strcmp(name, iName);
}

void NameCard::ChangePhoneNum(char* iPhone)
{
    strcpy_s(phone, iPhone);
}
```

Class name: NameCardImplementation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include "NameCard.h"

int main()
{
    ArrayList list;
    NameCard *pData(NULL);
    NameCard nc1("Alice", "010-1111-2222");
    NameCard nc2("Brandon", "010-2222-3333");
    NameCard nc3("Jack", "010-3333-4444");
    list.LInsert(nc1);
    list.LInsert(nc2);
    list.LInsert(nc3);
    //nc1.ShowNameCardInfo();
    //list.arr[0].ShowNameCardInfo();
    //std::cout << list.LCount() << std::endl;
    int a  = list.LFirst(pData);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    //if (list.LFirst(pData))
    //{
    //  pData->ShowNameCardInfo();
    //}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash is due to null pointer access in ArrayList::LFirst. 
From the limited code you have pasted, I see that there is no memory created for pData. 
NameCard *pData(NULL);

Are you attaching the memory for pData anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to ---NameCard* pData(nullptr); NameCard nc1("Tony", 010-1111-2222"); pData = &nc1; --- and it worked! However, do you have any idea how I make this code better? More specifically, how could I create memory for the pData when I declare it?

Comment: You need to use "new" operator for allocating memory dynamically for PData (new NameCard()) - Kindly accept the answer as it is found to be working fine for you.

Comment: Dynamically allocating memory solved the problem. Thank you so much!